# how to make android app swapping in circle

Tags: php, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I have icons as on the image below. I want the user to click&hold, then drop onto another icon. For each position, a different API is needed.
Suppose I click the north icon (the man). I want the user to move the man up to a new blank position.
[image]

#### Original question:

I have a circle and some points on circle. I want go one point to another point by swap. on each point a different api need to call. please check attached image. suppose I am on first circle(man pic) to left first circle. I dont want direct go to first white circle. I want user press image dont up finger from circle and goto first white circle and same next first let white circle to 2nd white circle and so on.
API is simple done in php

Comment: Is it, like clicking on a circle, to bring it to the first place? Need more clarity on question.

Comment: A hacky way can be that set ontouch listener on each circle image and on Action.MOVE set flags true & if user puts off the finger show error or else